# How to display only a table from a html file into a webview in Android

Tags: java, android, webview, web-scraping

I would like to know how does one show only a table inside a webview by fetching it directly from the given url. Consider for example the url: http://www.soccerstats.com/, in the right hand side we have several tables showing the played games and points, how do we do so for including only the table containing the details of Premier League in the webview. Otherwise, the only option parse each individual elements and then add one by one. Please help.

Comment: i think `table in html is not supported in android`

Comment: You should get the contents of the URL, parse the result to get only the desired table. Then, this table, you embed an HTML file to display itself in a WebView.

Comment: [SoccerSTATS.com - Terms and Conditions of Use](http://www.soccerstats.com/legal.asp)  **Usage terms** *"..You must not conduct any systematic or automated data collection activities such as scraping, data mining and data extraction on the Website without our express written consent,.."*  When you get that consent, ask them how they prefer your app. to access their content.  They may provide an API.

Comment: Hey Andrew, I would just like you to know that I wont do such a thing and i just highlighted it for considering it as an example only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty easily with [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).
So your code would look something like this.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String data = null;
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://wikipedia.com").get();
            data = doc.select("css_selector_here").html();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        wv.loadData(s, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }
}.execute();
```